# Palindrome LinkedList Leetcode challenge

Tags: python, class, palindrome

Given the following Leetcode challenge,

[Leet code challenge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/slGEF.png)

I have 2 questions:

1- I am confused about head =[1,2,3,4] in the question. To me, this looks like a whole linked list and not just a head. I would expect the head would be the first element in the input data array.

I think I am not sure how the head can equal multiple values in a list?

2- Below is the same code from the official solution and it's not working:

```
class ListNode:
    def __init__(self, val=0, next=None):
        self.val = val
        self.next = next   

class Solution:
    def isPalindrome(self, head: ListNode) -> bool:
        vals = []
        current_node = head
        while current_node is not None:
            vals.append(current_node.val)
            current_node = current_node.next
        return vals == vals[::-1]
```

If I run this code using these 2 lines:

`node = ListNode([1,2])`

`Solution().isPalindrome(node)`

I was expecting it to to output False for this example but it always outputs true because the vals is a nested list. The [::-1] python function doesn't work with nested lists.

Not sure what I am missing.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Point 1**
You have the correct understanding. What whey mean in attached screenshot is that the "head" is pointing to the first element of the linked list.

**Point 2**
The problem is with the constructor. ListNode represents a single node and the corresponding contructor `__init__(self, val=0, next=None)` is expecting two arguments:

- Value: Value of the node
- Next: Pointer to the next ListNode

I tried the following code and its returning the expected results:

```
#One that returns false:
s = Solution()
n1 = ListNode(1)
n2 = ListNode(1, n1)
n3 = ListNode(3, n2)
n4 = ListNode(1, n3)
head = n4;
result = s.isPalindrome(head);
print(result)

#One that returns true:
s = Solution()
n1 = ListNode(1)
n2 = ListNode(2, n1)
n3 = ListNode(2, n2)
n4 = ListNode(1, n3)
head = n4;
result = s.isPalindrome(head);
print(result)
```